# Ошибка при попытке записи в базу через Entity

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime

**Ситуация:** Формирую график рабочих смен, записывая в базу элементы типа `Schedule`:

```
public partial class Schedule
    {
        public int ScheduleID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DayStart { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DayEnd { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity1Start { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity1End { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity2Start { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity2End { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity3Start { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.TimeSpan> Activity3End { get; set; }
        public int Frequency { get; set; }
        public bool IsWorking { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

*(Тип сгенерирован Entity, потому что datafirst.)*

**Проблема:** При попытке записи в пустую таблицу методом `AddSchedule`, некоторые(не все) даты в полях `DayStart` и `DayEnd` вызывают исключение:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user
>   code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while starting a transaction
>   on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.

Вот сам метод  записи:

```
 public Schedule AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)
        {
            Schedule result = Data.ProcessDB.Schedule.Add(schedule);
            Data.ProcessDB.SaveChanges(); //Бессистемная ошибка
            return result;
        }
```

"Проблемные" даты всегда одни и те же, то есть проблема легко воспроизводится. 
Например без проблем записываются 1/09/2015, 3/09/2015, 4/09//2015 но 2,5 и 6 число вызывают исключение.

Поначалу я подумал, что проблема в разном формате записи у нас (dd/MM/YYYY) и в США (MM/dd/YYYY). Но тогда проблема проявлялась бы только с 13 числа любого месяца и только если бы я передавал дату строкой, что не так. Поэтому я отбросил этот вариант.

Где еще может быть "зарыта собака"  как посмотреть этот "Inner Exception" о котором говорится в ошибке?

Comment: See the inner exception for details. - Inner Exception можно посмотреть в отладчике - это просто свойство исключения. Или в строковом представлении - он будет виден в вызове exception.ToString() (но не будет виден в вызове exception.Message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Проблема решена:**

Метод записи `AddSchedule(Schedule schedule)` вызывался для каждого дня в месяце в цикле `foreach`, то есть около 30 раз подряд. Метод `Data.ProcessDB.SaveChanges();` попросту не успевал отрабатывать предыдущее значение, как ему уже поступало новое и вылетал с ошибкой.

**Решение:**

Изменил метод записи следующим образом:

```
public void AddSchedule(List<Schedule> schedules)
    {
        foreach(Schedule sched in schedules)
        {
            Data.ProcessDB.Schedule.Add(sched);
        }
        Data.ProcessDB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Это решило проблему.